# Facebook SDK Page Tabs (Not Administrator)

Tags: facebook, sdk

Is it possible to get Facebook Tab names from pages you are not an administrator? I want to see the Apps/Tabs a Facebook page has.

When I send the request

```
/my_page_id/tabs
```

I am returned with the type of data that I want from

```
/any_page_id/tabs
```

Is there any other way like apps or something similar.